# Bazel, how to skip "corrupt installation" on Centos6

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to compile tensorflow with EasyBuild on CentOs6, but Bazel is catching the wrong binutils dir, unfortunately a hardcoded one, ending with the wrong Assembler.

If I try to patch the hardcoded "-B/usr/bin" for the linker bazel tells me later the error below ...

"find %(builddir)s/ -type f | grep \"cpp/CROSSTOOL\" | xargs -n 1 sed -i \"s|-B/usr/bin/|-B$EBROOTBINUTILS|\"

Error: corrupt installation: file _embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL' modified.  Please remove 'install/c3fbdea9fb934f1ff0d8172c25d0dab2' and try again.
 (at easybuild/tools/run.py:469 in parse_cmd_output)

I've spent some time to see if there is a way to skip those stupid checksum tests, or to recalculate the checksums, but it's really not transparent to the user.

Any ideas how this can be solved ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, set the mtime of the file to 10 years into the future (it must be >10 years in the future; not just in the future):

```
touch -m -t 203712120101 path/to/file
```

EDIT: the reason Bazel checks the mtimes of the installation files is to avoid accidental changes to them. If you know what you're doing, i.e. deliberately patching the CROSSTOOL file, then this is the way to circumvent the check.

Comment: Thanks :-) Worked fine. 

The hardcoded -B/usr/bin is just wrong in some cases, I've told it the TensorFlow people.

Comment: [Do you mean in the CROSSTOOL file](https://cs.bazel.build/search?q=r%3Abazel+%22-B%2Fusr%2Fbin%22&num=50)?

Comment: At the end we patched unix_cc_configure.bzl:

build_str += "find %(builddir)s/ -type f | grep \"unix_cc_configure.bzl\" | xargs -n 1 sed -i \"s|-B/usr/bin|-B$EBROOTBINUTILS|\" && "
build_str += "find %(builddir)s/ -type f | grep \"unix_cc_configure.bzl\" | xargs -n 1 touch -m -t 202712120101 && "

Comment: This got me around the issue, but I had to update the time to be 10 years in the future from today (since this is an old post), e.g. 202901010101.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Try something like **`touch -m -c -r empty.cc *.bzl`** to copy the timestamp from another file.